# How do i use translate in the Controller using Zend?

Tags: zend-framework, internationalization, zend-translate

Usually i user translation in View with this code :

```
<?php echo $this->translate("hello"); ?>
```

How do i get a translation in the Controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're creating the zend_translate object in the bootstrap, you can set it in the Zend_Registry for later use:

```
Zend_Registry::set('translate', $translate);
```

and then use it in the controller:

```
$translate = Zend_Registry::get('translate');
$translate->translate("hello");
```

As far as I know, Zend_Controller doesn't include built-in support for zend_translate.

Answer (score 21):

To use translation in the controller:

```
$this->view->translate('Something to translate');
```

Or [create a translation action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown) if you want to keep everything clean and pretty (although I don't think it's worth the trouble in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Or using the service locator (ZF2):

```
$translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
$feed->setTitle($translator->translate('My RSS Feed'));
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer.